# Filter based on a range of Values

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

OK - So imagine I have a column with a number of street addresses:

```
1 Fred St
7 John St
3 Fred Avenue
12 John St
15 Alex st
```

In another sheet, I have a series of street names in which I am interested:

```
John
Fred
```

I want to filter the first sheet to display rows which contain either John or Fred. I've tried a filter based on a custom formula. This will find all the ones with John:

`=REGEXMATCH(A:A, "John")`

and this will work if `John` is in D1

`=REGEXMATCH(B:B, $D$1)`

First how do I get this latter one to work if D1 is in a different sheet? Can I prefix the sheet name somehow? Secondly, how do I get it to work based on a series of different values (like John and Fred) stored elsewhere.

`=REGEXMATCH(B:B, $D$1:$D$2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TEXTJOIN to concatenate all the cells of a range, avoiding empty cells: for example, this formula would take all column D. Obviously you can narrow it if you want, but just to show you:

```
=REGEXMATCH(B:B, TEXTJOIN("|",1,$D$1:$D))
```

Comment: Yeh that's great. What if D1..etc is on a different sheet? I now I should know this but I just started this like an hour ago...

Comment: If it's in another tab of the same spreadsheet: Sheet2!D1:D, if it's in another spreadsheet at all IMPORTRANGE("SHEETID","Sheet1!D:D")

Comment: Yeh I tried that - but don't we need those $ - like in $D$1 in your first reply?

And how about this - what if I want another column on the main sheet which has just the street name we matched?

Comment: If you use ARRAYFORMULAs like this one, you actually don't need the $ because you don't have to drag the formula. I didn't understand your second question

Comment: I hate to tell you this - and I must be missing the obvious. This works:

=REGEXMATCH(B:B, TEXTJOIN("|",1,$D$2:$D))

If I take the data in column D, and add it to a new sheet, "Sheet2", in column A, and change the formula to:

=REGEXMATCH(B:B, TEXTJOIN("|",1,Sheet2!A1:A))

I get no results. I tried this as well:

=REGEXMATCH(B:B, TEXTJOIN("|",1,Sheet2!A1:Sheet2.A))

Comment: If I use this formula in a new cell, on Sheet1, it shows contents of A1:A delimited by the pipe which is what we want - but in that filter expression it doesn't like it.

Comment: This works:

=REGEXMATCH(B:B, TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,Sheet2!$A$1:$A))

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While `REGEXMATCH()` will work in simple manner, you may also try the following-

```
=LAMBDA(lm,FILTER(lm,
MAP(lm,LAMBDA(x,OR(INDEX(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(SPLIT(x," "),TEXTJOIN("|",1,H2:H)))))))))
(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)))
```

[image]